# Data Science Site Statistics

Tags: discussion, statistics

I looked over the site stats and wanted to compare/baseline to other SE sites I use and I cannot locate them. Does anyone know where this can be accessed on other sites? Is it only a feature of sites in beta? It is interesting, but from my perspective mostly useless without some form of comparison or baseline...

Comment: One statistic that would be interesting to have: the percentage of questions asked here that are also on-topic on CV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you can get detailed site analytics for a site like Stack Overflow, but only with the highest level of reputation. For example it takes 25K reputation to see https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics  Mods can see it too.

You should be able to see stats for beta sites at `area51`, like http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37041/raspberry-pi

Otherwise I don't know of any other stats available, but I bet you want to benchmark against other beta sites.

Comment: Note, the area51 stats for launched sites are frozen.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the site analytics available at 5k reputation for beta sites and the area51 dashboard statistics, there is a comparison of all stack exchange sites available here:

- http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#questionsperday

Unfortunately, you can not filter that by beta sites.